# Magento version compatible with

Tags: magento

I need to be able to specify Magento version compatibility in the module's config.xml:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyCompany_MyModule>
            <version>0.9.0</version>
            <minimum_version>1.7</minimum_version>
        </MyCompany_MyModule>
    </modules>
    ...
```

Does this look right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of the day, I realized I can put what I need where ever I please. There's no Magento best practice as far as I know. My question came out of a need to use modman to deploy a list of modules from a Github. Here's some hacky code where this xml ended up being used:

```
... //after cloning the repositories, for each module:
$modules = glob('.modman/$moduleName/app/etc/modules/*.xml');
$filename = $modules[0];
$xmlString = file_get_contents($filename, FILE_TEXT);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlString);
$jsonStr = json_encode($xml);
$obj = json_decode($jsonStr);
$modules = $obj->modules;
foreach ($modules as $key=>$module){}
$fullName = explode('_', $key);
$namespace = $fullName[0];
$codePool = $module->codePool;
$channel = $codePool;

$configFile = ".modman/$moduleName/app/code/$channel/$namespace/$moduleName/etc/config.xml";
$configXml = file_get_contents($configFile, FILE_TEXT);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($configXml);
$jsonStr = json_encode($xml);
$obj = json_decode($jsonStr);
$modules = $obj->modules;
$module = reset($modules);

if (isset($module->minimum_version)) {

    $minimumVersion = $module->minimum_version;

    $magentoVersion = Mage::getVersion();

    $tooOld = version_compare($magentoVersion, $minimumVersion, '<');

    if ($tooOld < 0) {

        $exec = "modman remove $name";
        exec($exec, $output);
    }
}
```

Done.

Answer (score 0):

So in plain Magento there is no `minimum_version` tag in the config.xml there are a few things possible to achieve this sort of feature.

1. If you are making the extension public on Magento Connect you can specify the version that the extension is compatible,
2. You can use some sort of event to check what version of Magento you are using and then activate your extension based on that,
3. Simple wrap your extensions function calls with a check for Magento version,

I have personally used the last step myself, not when checking the version but when adding a active flag in the Magento admin system config for extensions.